# Как в Symfony validator сделать проверку свойства объекта зависимую от другого свойства

Tags: symfony, валидация

Есть модель в котором два свойства: $name и $required. 
Мне нужно проверить $name. Допускается пустой $namr, если $required == 0. 
Как сделать проверку $name зависящей от значения $require?

Создаю валидатор:

```
$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
->enableAnnotationMapping()
->addMethodMapping('loadValidatorMetadata')
->setTranslator($translator)
->setTranslationDomain('validators')
->getValidator();
```

В модель добавляю статический метод loadValidatorMetadata(). 
К в этом методе получить доступ к свойствам проверяемого объекта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написать костомный валидатор для вашей сущности.
И в методе validate уже делать все нужные проверки для сущности.
Ссылка на доку: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html